# Addition of data to the form in the view, displayed in the template

Tags: django, django-filter

It transmits data from one view to another. For example `forwarding=123` now I want forwarding to be displayed in my html template as in the example below.

[image]

How do I pass the 'forwarding' parameter to my get on the next view, so that it is visible in the template and that I can edit it later in the template?

**My next view**

```
def search(request, forwarding):
    product_list = Product.objects.all().order_by('created')
    product_filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=product_list) #How can i add here forwarding

    context = {'product_filter': product_filter,}
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

**My filters.py**

```
from .models import Product
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) parameter for forms.

```
def search(request, forwarding):
    product_list = Product.objects.all().order_by('created')
    initial = {'title': request.GET.get('forwarding')}
    product_filter = ProductFilter(
        request.GET,
        queryset=product_list,
        initial=initial,
    )
    context = {'product_filter': product_filter,}
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

I didn't notice you were using `FilterSet`'s. You can override the GET data as such:

```
def search(request, forwarding):
    product_list = Product.objects.all().order_by('created')
    data = dict(request.GET)
    if 'title' not in data:
        data['title'] = request.GET.get('forwarding')
    product_filter = ProductFilter(
        data,
        queryset=product_list,
    )
    context = {'product_filter': product_filter,}
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my situation, it raises this error: '__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial''.

Comment: I have changed the code as recommended, but it is not working properly. The data is not transferred and when I try to find anything, the data in the form changes to something like: '['test']' (of course, I enter the test itself and the rest is automatically added, this results in no search results.)

Comment: Sorry Maddie, I don't follow what you're doing. I can't help you without a lot more detail on what you're doing, what you expect to happen and what is happen. Also more of your code.